# How do I install the Worklight mobile client application into the Application Center

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am running the Worklight Server v5.0.0.3 Redhat Enterprise Linux 5.8 64b BYOL image in the iBM SmartCloud Enterprise. I can install apk files into the App Center from Worklight Studio on my laptop.

I now want to install one of these apps from the App Center to my smartphone. To do that I first need to install the Worklight mobile client application into the App Center. The file is  opt/IBM/Worklight/ApplicationCenter/installer/IBMApplicationCenter.apk.

But how do I actually install it? If I click on "Add Application" in the App Center it will search on my laptop drive, not on the server drive in the cloud.

Is there a way for me to install it on the WL Server, or do I actually have to download it to my laptop and then install it from there?

Comment: is your question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you did not read the IBM Worklight Application Center documentation...

Note that the below instructions are for the [Application Center in Worklight 5.0.6.x](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/topics/c_appcenter.html), but they should be fairly similar in 5.0.0.3 as well with some minor differences.

The documentation for v5.0.0.3 is available in [this zip file](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/wl_V5002_v5003_all_documentation.zip).

Here's a quick explanation:

1. There is an app called "App Center" (the IBMApplicationCenter.apk you've mentioned)
2. [You upload it](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/appcenter/t_adding_a_mobile_application.html) to the Application Center console - make sure to tick the "installer" checkbox in the upload form
3. You do the same for your ready Worklight apps (the .apk produced after generating it in Eclipse) - **do not** tick the 'installer' checkbox
4. Now you need to [install the "App Center" app on your device](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/appcenter/t_installing_the_client_on_an_and_mob.html).
5. Once that's done you should have a list of apps available to install on your device from within the "App Center" application.

I do, though, **strongly suggest** that you upgrade to the latest version of Worklight; many fixes have been done in all aspects, including Application Center.